# Can we directly migrate SQL Server 2008 to 2014 without changing anything in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2014

We have Visual Studio 2010 with .Net Framework 4.5
and SQL Server version 2008.

We are in the process of migrating SQL Serer 2008 to 2014.
I want to know the steps to migrate to 2014 and is there any settings or extensions or updates to be done for Visual Studio to make it compatible with SQL Server 2014?

Comment: Can you define "make it compatible"?

Answer (score 0):

For full support of SQL Server 2014 inside Visual Studio, you need to run at least [Visual Studio 2012 and have SSDT installed as outlined here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/archive/2014/03/25/sql-server-data-tools-for-sql-server-2014-is-available.aspx).

However, to connect to SQL Server from your application or from Visual Studio and to do basic operations against the database no update to Visual Studio 2010 is required.